# Calculating GPS uncertainty as a function of general position and time

Tags: gps, satellite

Is it possible to calculate the uncertainty in a GPS measurement at a given point at a given time by taking into account the number and positioning of the GPS satellites overhead?

People throw around general numbers (plus/minus 5m is common), but it seems to me it would clearly be a function of the two factors mentioned above. Why does nobody ever do this analysis?

There are also other, separate factors that introduce a variable amount of uncertainty, such as time delay for signal propagation in the ionosphere. Is this correction (and its uncertainty) similarly known and charted by any agency? Could this be included in an uncertainty analysis?

Comment: The +/- N distance is the uncertainty in the measurements from the signal. Most GPS software tells you what the uncertainty is for a given moment depending on the signals. The error with ionosphere and other factors that could not be measured in the field are accounted for in post-processing of measurements.

Comment: related ~ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86462/what-is-required-for-post-processing-differential-correction-and-can-garmin-un

Comment: Okay thanks, RomaH could you point me to any sources on how to do this correction or what its typical contribution to the overall measurement uncertainty is?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, there are at least two different aspects to be taken into account:

1. The measurement errors on the signals that are broadcast by the GPS/GNSS satellites and observed by the sensor. Those can vary according to the type of the signal observed (e.g., *pseudorange* or *phase* or *doppler* measurements) and to the characteristics of the media that the signals pass through.
2. The errors on the position that is computed (or estimated) based on the acquired measurements. Those can vastly vary and are normally measured in terms of *precision* (i.e., how much is the position repeatable) and of *accuracy* (i.e., how much is the position close to the *true* position).

The topic is ample (and quite fun) to explore. I can suggest the next references as good places where to start from:

- [Signals and measurement errors](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/GNSS_Measurement_features_and_noise).
- [Receiver noise](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Receiver_noise)
- [Positioning error](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Positioning_Error)

Good luck and enjoy the exploration.

Answer (score 1):

The "number and positioning of the GPS satellites overhead" is measured by the DOP (Dilution Of Position, Google it for more information, it has been around for the last 20 years).  Most GNSS receivers provide PDOP and HDOP values.  And when I started using high-accuracy receivers 11 years ago, we used to look at the DOPs in our location to find the best time of day to collect data.  When we started using GLONASS as well as GPS, the DOP variation over the course of the day dropped, and these days, assuming you are not stuck with a GPS-only receiver, a GNSS receiver typically tracks so many satellites that you can ignore DOPs.  Other factors, particularly how good the receiver and the antenna are, are much more important.

For example, the free GPSTest application by BarbeauDev running on my Nokia 7 Plus shows that I am tracking GPS, GLONASS, QZSS, Beidou, and Galileo, so right now I'm tracking around 34 satellites, and a Skyplot shows they are nicely spread around the sky.  GPSTest tells me that the Estimated Horizontal Accuracy is 3.2M, which I believe comes out of the Qualcom GNSS receiver in the phone.  In comparison, if I take my 9-year-old Trimble Geo 6000 XT, it only tracks GPS (GPS + GLONASS is an extra-cost option), so typically it tracks 8 to 10 GPS satellites at any time, and the accuracy estimate never drops below 5M unless I use real time corrections.  But if I capture the position of a fixed feature a couple of times a day for a few weeks, I can guarantee that the Geo 6000 positions will be closer together than the Nokia 7 Plus positions.  Geo 6000 will be much better than their pessimistic 5M estimate, I'll be lucky if the Nokia gets close to its 3.2M estimate.  I'd expect the average position to be about the same for both receivers, if I take a "long enough" set of positions (uBlox in their specifications averages the positions for 24 hours to get their accuracy specification).

Trimble or Leica or Ashtech or Topcon, etc. GNSS Receivers give more accurate results because they have more expensive receiver electronic components, maybe they use more sophisticated signal processing, and definitely they use bigger and better antennas than you'd get in a mobile phone or Garmin etc.